# When I am trying to run cordova it throw following error:

Tags: node.js, cordova

When I am trying to run cordova it throw following error:

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'umask'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/umask.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

Comment: What are you doing exactly? At which task this error occurs?

Comment: Describe your question properly.

Comment: When i was trying to run   follwing  command $ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

Comment: So what code is in that file / project? Also, if it is just that error, have you tried `npm install umask`?

Comment: Thank for help but now it throw following error          
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'